# How to disable tomcat7 from autostarting?

Tags: autostart, tomcat7

Most answers that I found on the Internet is something like this:

```
sudo update-rc.d tomcat7 disable
```

When I executed this line in ubuntu, I saw these warnings:

```
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `tomcat7' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `tomcat7' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

And tomcat7 still autostarted every time. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` and fix it. this is basically what update-rc.d is failing to operate on. not totally sure how, but it'll be explained in `/etc/init.d/README` and `man insserv`.

One possibility that may work is just delete `/etc/init.d/tomcat7`. I think you may be supposed to do this via `update-rc.d tomcat7 remove` though.